# This Javascript is extremely slow

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to accomplish:

I am trying to update abbr's title to the value of what is in the ".Left" and ".Right" classes, respectively. I've come up with a jQuery solution but it was too expensive in terms of load time and I am trying to come up with a Javascript solution but I'm stuck. I'm new to JS so I have a lot to learn about the DOM.

The HTML I gave repeats itself 100 times (same exact skeleton). How can I make my code more efficient? Also, I'm getting a "cannot set property title of null" error.

```js
var ratedSection = document.getElementsByClassName('RatedSection');
var ratedQuest = document.getElementsByClassName('RatedQuest');
var selector = document.getElementsByClassName('Selector');

for (var i = 0; i < ratedSection.length; i++) { //loops through ratedsection
  var left = ratedSection[i].querySelector('.Left');
  var right = ratedSection[i].querySelector('.Right');

  left = left.innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, " ");
  right = right.innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, " ");

  for (var j = 0; j < ratedQuest.length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < selector.length; k++) {
      var index = ratedQuest[j].querySelector('input').value;

      if (index == 1)
        selector[k].querySelector('abbr').title = left;

      else if (index == max)
        selector[k].querySelector('abbr').title = right;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="RatedSection">
  <tr class="Header">
    <td class="Left">Stuff
      <br>inside
      <br>here
    </td>
    <td class="Right">More
      <br>stuff
      <br>inside
      <br>here
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="RatedQuest">
    <td class="Selector">
      <abbr title>7</abbr>
      <abbr title>1</abbr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's remove some clutter and take a look at the looping code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ratedSection.length; i++)
  for(var j = 0; j < ratedQuest.length; j++)
    for(var k = 0; k < selector.length; k++)
```

I'm guessing you wanted to write this (pseudocode):

```
FOR EACH section IN PAGE
  FOR EACH quest INSIDE section
    FOR EACH selector INSIDE quest
```

But you're actually doing this:

```
FOR EACH section IN PAGE
  FOR EACH quest IN PAGE
    FOR EACH selector IN PAGE
```

Every pass of the loop, you're looking at a whole page of quest/selector items, not only at those inside the current section. You're getting the references to quests and selectors from `document`, not from the current section.

Instead of iterating 100 times, you're iterating 10000 times. Use `querySelector` on the section object when you enter the first loop

Comment: So, to get only the elements you want, just do something like ratedQuest = ratedSelection[i].getElementsByClassName('RatedQuest') and so forth.

Comment: Indeed, that should do it =) you can try it on a smaller page, and put `console.log` statements to verify that you're selecting the right elements

Comment: That explains it. It was taking 80 seconds to run that code... I appreciate the help!